# Vim key binding to call a function with input from user

Tags: vim

There might be a simple solution for this. I couldn't find any solution to it (I might be searching with wrong context)

Here is my requirement.

I wrote the below key mapping in vimrc. It should print the line "**Hello user_name.**" n times, where **n** and **user_name** are the user input once the key is pressed.

```
autocmd FileType ruby nnoremap <expr> <C-h>  :call FuncPrnt(<-syntax to pass input from user->)        

function! FuncPrnt(count, uname)
  let c=a:count
  let i=0
  while i<c
    call append(line("."), "Hello ".a:uname.".")
    let i+=1
  endwhile
endfunction
```

On Pressing the key user enters 3 and 'Ironman'. The output would be like

```
Hello Ironman.
Hello Ironman.
Hello Ironman.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler approach is to just use a non-`<expr>` mapping to prepare the Ex command without executing it:

```
nnoremap <C-h> :call FuncPrnt(,"")<left><left><left><left>
```

If you associate that with a filetype (such as "ruby" in your case), make sure you create a [local mapping](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-local) using `<buffer>`. Otherwise the mapping will be global and will work on every buffer and not only those with Ruby source files.

If you use an `autocmd` in your vimrc, make sure you wrap it in an [`augroup`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#%3Aaugroup) to prevent getting duplicated commands if you reload your vimrc.

Alternatively, you can add filetype mappings for Ruby in a file `~/.vim/ftplugin/ruby.vim` which gets automatically loaded by Vim whenever a file of type Ruby is loaded. (That way you don't need to use explicit `autocmd`s, Vim will take care of those details on your behalf.)

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. Just in case someone else is searching for similar solution

```
autocmd FileType ruby nnoremap <expr> <C-h> input("", ":call FuncPrnt(,\"\")<left><left><left><left>")
```

will print the command and waits for the user to edit. Once the user edits and enters it is executed

Answer (score 0):

Thinking outside of the box a little bit (questioning the premise), perhaps the best in this case is to define a [user-defined command](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#user-commands) instead of a mapping.

You can define one here with:

```
command! -buffer -bar -count=1 -nargs=1 FuncPrnt
  \ call FuncPrnt(<count>, <q-args>)
```

That way you can use it with:

```
:3FuncPrnt Ironman
```

If you omit the count, 1 will be used. (You can pick a different default as the argument to `-count=N`.)

You can use Tab completion for `FuncPrnt`, so perhaps `:3Fu<Tab>` or even `:3F<Tab>` might be enough to complete the command.

This might end up being quicker or more convenient to type than `<C-H>3<right><right>`, since it doesn't involve moving your hand to the arrow keys.